# How to remove the empty space at the bottom of a grid layout

Tags: html, css

grid template area is causing the bottom of my website to have an empty blank space, I have tried using grid template rows to make 6 rows but it doesn't work either. looking through the console, it doesn't seem to be the fault of any footer 's element padding/margin either.

[image: bb]

HTML

```css
 body{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas:
            "header header"
            "headingImage headingImage"
            "container container"
            "mainContent mainContent"
            "formContainer formContainer"
            "footer footer";
        grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    }
```

```html
     <div class="footerContainer">
                <div class="contact">
                    <ul>
                            <li >Contact the author:</li>
                            <li >xxxx</li>
                            <li ><a href="xxxxx">xxxxx</a></li>
                            <li >Contact: xxxxx</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="social">
                    <br>
                    <P>Follow us on our socials:</P>
                    <div id="socialIcon">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src="images/instagram.png" alt=""></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt=""></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <p id="copyright"> content and photo used are strictly for educational purposes only. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <button  id="backToTop"><span class="arrow up"></button>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

Comment: You should show the rest of the grid css (how are you positioning the children?) and more of the html (do you have content for all the areas?)

Comment: also, your `<span class="arrow up">` tag is not closed. Make sure your html is correct or the browser will do weird stuff

Comment: thanks, i have enclose the <span> here is the link to the code: https://jsfiddle.net/acidpower97/pzrjuasd/2/

Comment: You have a lot of `<br>` tags that are being pushed to the last row of the grid, don't use `br` tags for layouts

Comment: after removing all the `br` tags, you have one `p` with id `copyright` with a margin bottom that's adding more space too

Comment: oh my <br> really was the cause of the empty space, can you explain to me why it is pushed all the way to the bottom of the page instead of inside the .mainContent

Comment: Because those `<br>` are not inside the `section#mainContent` tag, they are siblings, not children. If you move the tags inside the previous section they'll be inside. Since you are using areas, the browser will put the content in the named areas and the it will start putting each element on a new empty grid position after all the named areas

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, but the `<br>` is inside the `<p>` which is inside `section#mainContent` so shouldn't it automatically follow the grid-template i assigned?

Comment: There are a lot of `br` tags right after that section. The children are not a problem, the siblings are. You have 3 `br` after `section#mainContent` and 2 `br` after `div#formContainer`. In that jsdiffle link I see no `br` tags inside any `p`.

Comment: oh i see it , thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

```
grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
```

is completely **useless** since it describes what the browser would do if you didn't define it at all, meaning if you remove the declaration, nothing will change.

Also note that for any element to take the "remaining" space of a grid, it needs to be defined using a fractional unit `fr`. For the browser to know how much that is - the "remaining" space - the grid container needs to have a defined `height` (or at least `min-height`).

I suggest you try this:

```
body { min-height: 100vh; margin: 0; grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto) 1fr; }
```

Comment: i have tried and it did not work for me but just for clarification, grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto) 1fr; creates 5 rows with the last one filling the remaining space?

Comment: Yes, the last one referring to the 5th row. If you place any items below that 5th row, these additional rows automatically get assigned an implicit `auto` height row.

Comment: i get it now, thanks for the clarification!